# Chinese letters appear when i change the content of an email in the junk mail using c#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, html-email, office-automation

I am creating a plugin in the outlook desktop that if the user use it on suspicous emails, it will change the content of the email by adding random characters to the urls so it is not valid anymore , everything is working correctly except when the email is in the junk mail or the spam  folder , in this case after successfully changing the content (you can see it for a brief second) the content is changed to chinese letters , this is in c# using MailItem Library , did anyone face the same problem ?
This is the Original mail

https://www.google.com/

https://www.facebook.com/

https://www.youtube.com/

and the result email in case of the junk mail is this  :

ℼ佄呃偙⁅呈䱍倠䉕䥌⁃ⴢ⼯㍗⽃䐯䑔䠠䵔⁌⸳⼲䔯≎ാ㰊呈䱍ാ㰊䕈䑁ാ㰊䕍䅔丠䵁㵅䜢湥牥瑡牯•佃呎久㵔䴢⁓硅档湡敧匠牥敶⁲敶獲潩⁮㘱〮ㄮ㜵㘲㈮㄰㠱㸢਍吼呉䕌㰾启呉䕌ാ㰊䠯䅅㹄਍䈼䑏㹙਍ℼⴭ䌠湯敶瑲摥映潲⁭整瑸瀯慬湩映牯慭⁴ⴭാഊ㰊㹐䘼乏⁔䥓䕚㈽버뷤莑臥薁釥趱胥閉ꗤ莁듢꾼跣莽郤钑ꃤ钵臢뎸볢꾔觢뺴냣袑뇤뺴냣袕釤뺴냣趕藤ꂠ釥邵藥閥뗣ꊌ맦뒕釧궐臧ꖉ賤边闤躑裢뒕釧꾠뗦겭賦ꢅ跧ꖑ铧뒙ꃣꊸ꣠벴釥膁藤趕裢螕闦늅뷦늉賤边闤躑裢趍铤뢍藦꺝臢鎕駧ꖉ飧ꖉꗦ꾹蓣뚸룢놔裣뚸胣놄裢뺴냣钥뇤薹볢钥뇤薹꣠벼闤膑든誰뷤蒥든誰듢궀뷦꺙觧뒕臢ꚉ뗦ꂐꇧ뒽뇦ꆥ臢ꚽ뗦ꆑ듢궸꣠趨胥뺰뷤躑賥覩뗣늸鏨벒鋨ꖇ雮膦蟨薖ꋨꒇ雮肂꟨閒단ꊇ諮뒊돫꾎黩ꊷ鋮邾蟩钒苪꒗諮膲ꏫ뎊諫꒓諮覺鏫뺎ꫨꖇ鋮놶鏫뺎ꫨ꒗鋮醆鏫뺎ꫨ꒗鋮薒ꏫꂒ蛨ꎗ鋮鲊꟫ꖞ雪ꞇ黮覾菨ꊒ軨ꖇ鋮릖韫钒諪ꊇ黮ꆖ蟪ꎚ蛪ꚗ雮貂꟨ꖚ髫ꊇ髮閚럨늚ꛪꊇ軮领菨꺎뫪ꎳ軮颊ꏨ꺎苫ꎃ軮뢊ꏪ趖닫ꖇ鋮閲菫뺖뻪ꖇ鋮閲鏫뺎ꫨꒃ鋮薖꟫蒂뛨꒣鋮醾꟫馂뛨ꊓ諮뒶돨ꂚ뻪ꚗ黮醊蟩ꖚ苪ꚷ諮膶韩뒞ꋫꞃ髮薲꟫ꦚ苪ꞧ髮薶蟨뒊뛪ꂓ苮뒪菫誎苩꒣鋮릾蟨钒軩꒗軮袶菫뺊蛨ꖧ鋮首ꏨ붞ꋪꞇ髮ꆂ럨ꦚꋪꚷ髮閊럫낞諫ꚇ軮ꦎ돫꾞黫ꖇ髮ꖢ蟪뎚ꛪꖧ黮膖꟨꾚鋫ꊧ髮붞럩꾚닪ꚳ髮떾ꏨ꾚뫫ꞇ雮膂韪ꢚ軫ꚧ雮覞蟨ꖞ뻪ꚗ黮趒돫몞뻪ꞷ髮ꆂ럨ꦚꋪꚷ髮閊럫낞諫ꚇ髮鲺럫꾚黪ꊧ髮붎럫궊닫ꎧ鋮袲꟫銂뛨꒣軮릊ꏪ趒닫ꎧ苮ꢶ鏨벒苪꒗軮떚菪ꊞ鋫ꞷ諮벪돩꾞黫ꚇ黮趦韪ꢚ뫪ꚗ髮붂蟩늚雪ꚣ髮趆꟨ꖚ뻪ꊧ髮붎럫궎諪ꞇ黮膒꟪뎊뻪ꞷ雮膞韪ꢚ軫ꚧ雮覞蟨ꖞ뻪ꚗ諮릒韨Ꚛ軪ꚷ髮궾돨꺚뻪ꎃ鋮蒾菫뺖諨ꂓ軮낪꟨节뫫ꎃ雮覊鏫뺎ꫨꊇ雮覢꟩薊뛫ꞇ黮膒꟪뎊뻪ꞷ雮膞韪ꢚ軫ꚧ雮覞蟨ꖞ뻪ꚗ諮릒럫릞雫ꚧ諮릖럫ꎊ뛪ꎣ黮醢蟨뒎軫ꊳ黮鶞蟨랚ꋪꚇ髮릦꟨Ꞟ雪ꞧ髮閒꟫꒚ꛫꞇ髮視꟫ꖚ軪ꊷ諮벲꟫膒닫ꎧ苮ꢶꏨ벎諩ꂣ鋮袲꟫銂뛨꒓鋮ꂂ韩銎髨ꚃ黮醒蟨낚ꋪꚇ髮릦꟨Ꞟ雪ꞧ髮閒럨ꒊꫫꞳ髮薒럪ꎞ뻪ꞧ髮놚럩꾚뫪ꚗ黮蒾韩떞軫ꚷ黮趺鏨꾎黫ꎃ軮蒢돫떚ꋪꊗ髮붒돨궚ꋪꚷ髮꒶韫Ꚛ鋫ꊗ髮릦韩낊鋫ꞇ髮ꖊ럩꺚뛪ꊗ諮떆韨뚚닪ꊗ髮閊韩Ꞛ닪ꊗ黮ꆖ꟨낞雪ꚗ髮릾ꏫꊞꋪꞇ髮ꆂ럨ꦚꋪꚷ髮閊럫낞諫ꚇ軮ꦎ돫꾞軫ꚷ髮붮韩뚚諫ꚷ諮릞럫ꎊ뛪ꞗ黮趖韪뒚뻪ꊷ軮鲆鏩늎苫ꎓ髮ꂾ럩꾞뛪ꊗ髮ꆎ럨ꖊ껪ꚧ黮邶韩ꢚ뛪ꞇ黮醖돨궞鋫ꚧ諮떞럨ꦚ뛪ꞣ髮놆蟩ꦞ뛪ꚷ髮놖꟨ꆚ뛪ꞇ髮閊럨뎚ꛪꎇ鋮蒾菫뺖諨ꂓ軮낪꟨节뫫ꎃ鋮颾꟫辎鋩ꂣ諮벲꟫邂뛨ꂣ諮벲럫芖鋨ꂓ軮낪菪꾒鋩ꎧ닣꾘매钹볢邹꣠趨볢芽ꗥ뺴냣꾠뗤貹⼼但呎㰾倯ാഊ㰊䈯䑏㹙਍⼼呈䱍>

i checked the other parts , i tried the same method in the sent folder, inbox , and deleted , all of them work correctly , the problem occurs only in the Junk Mail

**Update:**

I checked the same process on the trash file for yahoo mail working on the outlook , there was no problem , so i think that the problem is exclussive for outlook  junkMail

**Update:**
So i found the problem , outlook for some reason they change any email in th junk mail into plain text , and what i was trying to do is change the html body , so i do not know what happens in the middle, but changing the HtmlBody , was creating the mojiBake , once i tried editting the Body instead of the Html Body i was getting normal text, here is a reference to where i found that :[Microsoft](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/junk-email-converting-to-plain-text/c2985ace-cce3-49f4-bd98-b017442d4f3c)

Comment: Dump the hex bytes of the messed-up string. Notice that it's ASCII, or possibly UTF-8, but you are interpreting it as UTF-16LE. You are not handling character sets properly, resulting in mojibake.

Comment: What code exactly do you use for changing emails in the junk emails folder?

Comment: Have you tried using the Outlook object model without any third-party libraries involved?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev i am using the Microsoft.office.Interop.Office.MailItem , i get htmlBody of the mail , using regex to find any links , then if a link found then i insert the random characters, i debug the code and untill  the end even after saving the new body , it is showing the correct body (and in cases of other folder"other than junk mail" it is working correctly) but in case of the Junk mail i am getting this.  
i only tried the MailItem , and the app is working properly , but what i do not understand what makes the difference between other folders and the junk mail

Comment: Glad you have found the cause! When you compose a new post for developers some piece of code you use would always be helpful.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev thank you  for your help , i am still  new in posting , next time i will be publishing some of the code, but thank you anyway.